# Emailing log files from a Windows 8 App

Tags: c#, windows-runtime, windows-store-apps

I'm writing a Windows Store application where I have to send log files back to the developer (me) whenever a fatal exception occurs.

My first idea was to do this through an e-mail (for example, to dev@myapp.com)

From what I've read, the correct way of doing this is to make my app a Share Source and, when the exception occurs, I open the share charm programmatically by calling `DataTransferManager.ShowShareUI()` on the UI thread.

Ideally, the user will choose the Mail App.
I was able to set the mail content and attach the zip file with the logs to be sent.
However, I am not able to set the destination (dev@myapp.com). Obviously, it doesn't make any sense to have the user type the destination of this email.

Is there a more suitable solution for my problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Mircosoft's Mail app is dumb app I think. Each developer wants such feature that one should be able to set to/cc/bcc fields programmatically also apart from subject & email body.

From my perspective you can create web service which will store the exception details plus user comments into database or you can set SMTP on server side to mail you.

One more paid solution is to use [Mail.dll](http://www.limilabs.com/mail-for-windows-store) for full fledged mail experience.

Comment: Yeah I think I'll go with building my own service, so the app will be able to POST the logs there. I was trying to avoid that, because I'll have to assure 24/7 availability. I had already looked into other (free) mailing options, but I found none.

Answer (score 1):

Use the telemetry features built into the platform.  In the web portal, you can review [the quality of your app](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/hh967782.aspx) (crashes, hangs, general usage) to receive the information you are interested in.

Telemetry data collection needs to be enabled in your Windows Store developer account and more details can be found on [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/hh967787.aspx).

Comment: But what if I want the user to submit a comment (describing what he was doing, etc) along with the logs?

Comment: If that's the case, you'll need to use another mechanism - e.g., directly collecting this info in your app and sending it to your email account.  That being said, the response rate will be lower when you require additional steps from the user, and the objective data (crash dumps) will likely be much more valuable than the subjective data (user comments).

Answer (score 0):

You should use logging services like [MarkedUp](https://markedup.com/). I personally use it for my Windows 8 application and it's wonderful and easy to integrate.